# looking for values from another table where they do not exist in a given group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

SHOPPING

| date | id_customer | id_shop | id_fruit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28.03.2018 | 7423 | 123 | 1 |
| 13.02.2019 | 8408 | 354 | 1 |
| 28.03.2019 | 7767 | 123 | 9 |
| 13.02.2020 | 8543 | 472 | 7 |
| 28.03.2020 | 8640 | 346 | 9 |
| 13.02.2021 | 7375 | 323 | 9 |
| 28.03.2021 | 7474 | 323 | 8 |
| 13.02.2022 | 7476 | 499 | 1 |
| 28.03.2022 | 7299 | 123 | 4 |
| 13.02.2023 | 8879 | 281 | 2 |
| 28.03.2023 | 8353 | 452 | 1 |
| 13.02.2024 | 8608 | 499 | 6 |
| 28.03.2024 | 8867 | 318 | 1 |
| 13.02.2025 | 7997 | 499 | 6 |
| 28.03.2025 | 7715 | 499 | 4 |
| 13.02.2026 | 7673 | 441 | 7 |

FRUITS

| id_fruit | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | pear |
| 3 | grape |
| 4 | banana |
| 5 | plum |
| 6 | melon |
| 7 | watermelon |
| 8 | orange |
| 9 | pineapple |

I would like to find fruits that have never been bought in a specific id_shop

I tried with this:

```
SELECT
    s.idshop,
    s.id_fruit ,
    f.name
FROM
    shopping s
    LEFT JOIN fruit f ON f.id_fruit = s.id_fruit 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM
    fruit f1
    WHERE f1.id_fruit = s.id_fruit 
    )
```

but it does not work...

Comment: Doesn't work tells exactly nothing about the real issue. Please, show desired output and description of how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need an OUTER JOIN, but that should be RIGHT JOIN along with NULL values picked from **shopping** table after join applied, considering your current query such as

```sql
SELECT f.*
  FROM shopping s
 RIGHT JOIN fruit f
    ON f.id_fruit = s.id_fruit
 WHERE s.id_fruit IS NULL
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d44ce4a542bd8c7c3c4ef8e0ac59f0b9)</kbd>